# not able to fetch api response

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have written an API where I am generating data in JSON format.
Now I am calling same API on react frontend. If response is generated we will display a success page else we will divert to same page. So I have written these code when I submit user id and password on submit event validateLogin API has been called, but I am not able to execute body of API response.

```
onSubmit = async => {
  const { user_mail, user_pass1 } = this.state

  const payload = { user_mail, user_pass1}
   
  api.validateLogin(payload).then((res) =>{
      alert('Success');
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
      alert('Failed');
    })
}
```

Here nothing is executing. Can you please help me to execute response body?

Comment: something wrong with how you are calling onSubmit, can you show the complete code.
or maybe something wrong with `api.validateLogin`, check its definition too.

Comment: btw you have syntax error, it needs to be `onSubmit = async () => {` not `onSubmit = async => {`. you are missing the brackets

Comment: `onSubmit = async => {...` isn't valid syntax for an arrow function. Please fix and see if you still have issue.

Comment: Try console logging something inside the function to see if it is executed. Could you also show the api.validateLogin function.

Comment: onSubmit  = async() => {

    const { user_mail, user_pass1 } = this.state

    const payload = { user_mail, user_pass1}
       
      api.validateLogin(payload).then((res) =>
        alert('Success')
      )
      .catch((err) =>{
        alert('Failed');
      })
  }